# One system is stuck on an older Cumulative Update

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-core

I've set up a Service Fabric cluster on Azure, which is built on top of *Virtual machine scale sets*. It has two scale sets, one with three nodes and one with a single node. Both scale sets run *WindowsServer 2016-Datacenter-Server-Core*, the only difference is that the one with a single node runs on a cheaper VM size.

I managed to install [KB4093119 (OS Build 14393.2189)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093119) and [KB4093120 (OS Build 14393.2214)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093120) on the three identical nodes via `sconfig`, but the single node is stuck on [KB4088889 (OS Build 14393.2155)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4088889), it says there are no updates available:

> Search for for (A)ll updates or (R)ecommended updates only? a
>
> Searching for all applicable updates...
>
> List of applicable items on the machine:
>
> There are no applicable updates.

The three identical nodes have this output from `systeminfo`:

```
Hotfix(s):                 5 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB3192137
                           [02]: KB4049065
                           [03]: KB4089510
                           [04]: KB4093137
                           [05]: KB4093120
```

The single node has this output from `systeminfo`:

```
Hotfix(s):                 4 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB3192137
                           [02]: KB4049065
                           [03]: KB4089510
                           [04]: KB4088889
```

This is the Windows Update log from the most recent update attempt:

```
2018/05/03 13:05:50.9029890 956   3128  Shared          * START * Service startup
2018/05/03 13:05:50.9096384 956   3128  Agent           WU client version 10.0.14393.2155
2018/05/03 13:05:50.9098252 956   3128  Agent           SleepStudyTracker: Machine is non-AOAC. Sleep study tracker disabled.
2018/05/03 13:05:50.9098846 956   3128  Agent           Base directory: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution
2018/05/03 13:05:50.9101255 956   3128  Agent           Datastore directory: C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1046025 956   3128  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1046218 956   3128  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1050846 956   3128  Shared          Network state: Connected
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1492758 956   3128  Misc            LoadHistoryEventFromRegistry completed, hr = 8024000C
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506450 956   3780  Agent           Initializing global settings cache
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506455 956   3780  Agent           WSUS server: NULL
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506458 956   3780  Agent           WSUS status server: NULL
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506462 956   3780  Agent           Alternate Download Server: NULL
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506465 956   3780  Agent           Fill Empty Content Urls: No
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506469 956   3780  Agent           Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1506473 956   3780  Agent           Windows Update access disabled: No
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1512557 956   3780  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2018-05-03 15:33:28, not idle-only, not network-only
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1571467 956   3128  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 3.
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1571518 956   3128  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1571563 956   3128  Shared          Power status changed
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1572517 956   3128  Agent           Initializing Windows Update Agent
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1574857 956   3128  DownloadManager Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1582212 956   3128  Agent           CPersistentTimeoutScheduler | GetTimer, returned hr = 0x00000000
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1751105 956   3880  Shared          Effective power state: AC
2018/05/03 13:05:51.1751113 956   3880  DownloadManager Power state change detected. Source now: AC
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2628123 956   3780  Agent           * START * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: cscript.exe  Id = 1]
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2628174 956   3780  Agent           Added service 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 to sequential scan list
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2657024 956   4852  Agent           * END * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: cscript.exe  Id = 1]
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682917 956   4852  Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: cscript.exe  Id = 1
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682926 956   4852  Agent           Online = Yes; AllowCachedResults = No; Ignore download priority = No
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682933 956   4852  Agent           Criteria = IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'""
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682963 956   4852  Agent           ServiceID = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} Third party service
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682968 956   4852  Agent           Search Scope = {Machine}
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2682995 956   4852  Agent           Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-21-2687739569-3004106656-2140684595-500
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2683001 956   4852  Agent           RegisterService is set
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  4388                  Unknown( 12): GUID=eb73583d-5481-33b4-202d-9bb270eddffa (No Format Information found).
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2711175 956   4852  Misc            Got 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 redir SecondaryServiceAuth URL: 117cab2d-82b1-4b5a-a08c-4d62dbee7782""
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2721640 956   4852  SLS             CoCreateInstance Failed: hr = 0x80040154
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2721664 956   4852  Agent           Failed to retrieve SLS response data for service 117cab2d-82b1-4b5a-a08c-4d62dbee7782, error = 0x80040154
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2721688 956   4852  Agent           Caller Service Recovery failed to opt in to service 117cab2d-82b1-4b5a-a08c-4d62dbee7782, hr=0X80040154
2018/05/03 13:05:51.2742668 956   4852  Misc            Got 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 redir Client/Server URL: https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2018/05/03 13:05:51.9867532 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}, Server URL = https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2018/05/03 13:05:51.9868666 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  OK to reuse existing configuration
2018/05/03 13:05:51.9868694 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  Existing cookie is valid, just use it
2018/05/03 13:05:52.6163585 956   4852  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0084185 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 2
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0084199 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  Sync of Updates 0x8024402f
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0092829 956   4852  ProtocolTalker  SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed 0x8024402f
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0117237 956   4852  Agent           Failed to synchronize, error = 0x8024402F
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0605156 956   4852  Agent           Exit code = 0x8024402F
2018/05/03 13:06:42.0605448 956   4852  Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = <<PROCESS>>: cscript.exe  Id = 1
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  5116                  Unknown( 16): GUID=eb73583d-5481-33b4-202d-9bb270eddffa (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  5116                  Unknown( 17): GUID=eb73583d-5481-33b4-202d-9bb270eddffa (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  5116                  Unknown( 19): GUID=eb73583d-5481-33b4-202d-9bb270eddffa (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  5116                  Unknown( 20): GUID=eb73583d-5481-33b4-202d-9bb270eddffa (No Format Information found).
1601/01/01 00:00:00.0000000 2288  4388                  Unknown( 10): GUID=fe1b6309-dedb-392e-308c-ec757efded1a (No Format Information found).
```

Comment: Your problem: `Failed to synchronize, error = 0x8024402F`! Check this for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/1165734/windows-10-update-error-0x8024402f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has resolved itself, the most recent CU was available for installation. So I guess the answer here is to just wait a couple weeks.